# How can I create a culture specified string to show day of the week and time?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime object, how can create a culture specified string to show day of the week and time?

e.g. for "Wed 23:00" or "Thu 1:00 AM" 
some cultures use 24 hr format, some culture  use 12 hr format

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

I don't see a format which match my need.

Comment: Start with [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) and search from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can create a culture specified string to show day of the week and
>   time?

Generally using with [`DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx), you can generate your string representation in a specific format and culture specified.

> some cultures use 24 hr format, some culture use 12 hr format

There is no such a thing. 24-hour clock formats and 12-hour clock formats are belongs on .NET Framework as a [custom date and time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a specific culture. For example; `h` and `hh` specifiers are for 12-hour formats and `H` and `HH` specifiers are for 24-hour formats. Also the culture you used should not have [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator(v=vs.110).aspx) as an empty strings. Otherwise, it won't display even if you use [`tt` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ttSpecifier) in your format.

Based on your outputs, if your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) is not *english-based* one, you need to use an english-based culture (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) because `Wed` and `Thu` are [abbreviated names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.abbreviateddaynames(v=vs.110).aspx) of them.

For example;

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 6, 3, 23, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("ddd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // Wed 23:00
```

and

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 6, 4, 1, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("ddd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // Thu 1:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a CultureInfo object with your desired culture
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

// get a DateTime from wherever
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

// pass the culture during formatting
String s = dt.ToString(culture);
```

You can pass the culture to any of the overloads of `ToString` that take an `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the end goal is the [Humanizer project](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) might help